# Command line plotting of xvg using grace

Tags: graph, xmgrace

I have an xvg file I wish to draw a graph of it using command line grace. However, I have no idea how to read the file into grace nor how to graph it once it is read. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: probably `xmgrace (data filename)`? [Source](http://mintaka.sdsu.edu/reu/grace.printout.html)

Comment: tried that it didn't work. I'm pretty sure that would have worked if I used xmgrace(the version with gui) but I am using grace(command line only no gui). thank you though

Comment: And the output of your attempt was?

Comment: it treats the file name as an unexpected token(this is a bash error) when the program has already been invoked in the terminal and I try it the program simply says there is an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just type "xmgrace filename" to plot the graph, if the file contains only numeric data.
You can also plot specific columns as shown below.

1. xmgrace -block filename -bxy 1:3
2. xmgrace -block filename -bxy 1:3 -bxy 1:2
3. xmgrace -block filename1 -bxy 1:2 -block filename2 -bxy 1:2

Comment: If the user has a tabular data file with more than two columns then typing "xmgrace filename" will give the following error message: "Can not use more than one column of strings per set". Unless the file has exactly two columns you must use the block data command `-block` and then specify the columns like in your three examples.